# Can anyone identify a fungus with a tiny fruiting body that I found in a plant pot

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I recently found what I think are fungi in the growing medium in a 30 cm pot that contains an epiphyllum 'orchid' (cactus). There are several that appear new and more that look old or are decaying.  I've included a picture with the fruiting body on the left - the coin is 1.8 cm in diameter and the small round ball is Osmocote.

The fruiting feels 'woody' when I touch it and is close to or touching the soil surface.  I let the soil get kind of dry between waterings and I'm in Southern California where it is hot.  The soil surface gets no direct sun. I've not repotted the plant but the soil is well draining and appears to have woody material in it.

I realize that it is unlikely that it will be identified to species but I'd like to know a bit about it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I took a look with a magnifying glass and found the fruiting bodies of 'Bird's Nest Fungi' that eat dead plant material.

So the answer is 'Bird's Nest Fungus'.

[image: Bird Next Fungus Fruiting Boday]

Comment: Excellent, when patience pays off :)

Answer (score -1):

Cyathus cf.fimicola
Black peridioles not densely packed within basidiocarp
Peridioles shiny; basidiocarp conspicuously shaggy[image]

Comment: This answer could be improved if you were to include complete sentences in order to clarify what you mean. Perhaps include a picture (with source properly attributed) to support your conclusion.

Comment: As I asked, could you add attribution to the picture ensuring the copyright is respected. As the notice on your post states, also add a reference and an explanation why your answer is correct, using whole sentences.

Comment: I have already added attribution in the edit summary

Comment: The place to add it would be in the body of the post. You'd need to also cite the licence that entitle you to reproduce the picture here, as it's a requirement of the whole Stackexchange network - and a legal requirement in many jurisdictions. Don't forget to edit the text to explicitly explain why your example answers the question.